# ReactJs: render a collection of dynamic components

Tags: reactjs

I'm rather new to react.js and I wonder if it's possible to render a collection of different components with React?
For example I have a ContainerComponent class with a property childComponents which I want to use like this:

```
var childComponents = [];

childComponents.push(<TextComponent text={this.props.text} />);
childComponents.push(<PictureComponent src={this.props.image} />);

return (
    <ContainerComponent
        title={this.props.title}
        innerComponents={childComponents} />
)
```

So the problem is that I can't call child components' render function in loop to generate single output of all children. How could render method of ContainerComponent look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place all the components like you would normally do:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.innerComponents}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Normally, the following code should work fine for your needs:

```
<ContainerComponent
   title={this.props.title}
>
  <TextComponent text={this.props.text} />
  <PictureComponent text={this.props.image} />
</ContainerComponent>
```

Comment: Not working for me. It just renders nothing. And I can't catch the error.

Comment: Realized, the map is not required. Not sure why it is not working.

Comment: It looks similar to this.props.children.

Comment: The second example will work, but I need to render dynamic components **within** reusable containers.

Comment: I tested the first method with this JSFiddle and it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vijayst/69z2wepo/55817/

Comment: Works.. seems like issues with my code. Thanks for help!